# I want to share a language I created. But I only have a sound file of it? Can I share a link?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, asking-questions, new-users

Just wondering about something. I'm new to this community. Am I okay to create a question in which I link a sound file? In the sound file I speak my language. And I have a question about it.

Thanks! Looking forward to joining the community.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's fine to share audio recordings here. But if you can speak your language then you should also be able to transcribe it using the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). Please do that for your questions, because not everyone is able to listen to recordings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Just make sure to upload the audio file here such that it is permanently available together with your question. Providing it at some external site leads to stale links invalidating the question in the long run.

Comment: Does SE host audio? I thought it only hosted images.